# wpautop() - when shortcode attributes are on new lines -breaks args array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, shortcode

I have a custom shortcode tag with a few attributes, and I would like to be able to display its attributes on new lines - to make it more readable to content editors:

```
[component
    attr1 ="value1"
    attr2 ="value of the second one"
    attr3 ="another"
    attr4 ="value"
    ...
    attrN ="valueN"]
```

The reason behind this requirement is that a few attributes might be quite verbose in content.  Unfortunately, `wpautop()` adds some nasty extra markup that breaks the `args` array like this (using php `print_r($args)`):

```
Array ( [0] => attr1 [1] => ="value1"
/> [3] => attr2 = [4] => "value [5] => of [6] => the [7] => second [8] => one"
/> [10] => "" //...and more like this)
```

I've tried with the attributes **inline**:

```
[component attr1 ="value1" attr2 ="value of the second one" ="value"... attrN ="valueN"]
```

and the output is as expected:

```
Array ( [attr1] => value1 [attr2] => value of the second one [attr3] => //...and so on)
```

is there any way to have the attributes intented and avoid that extra markup that breaks the `$args` array?

Comment: Do you know that this is cause by wpautop because you've tried to disable it? I think this sounds more like you're having a problem with shortcode_parse_atts()...

Comment: Not sure when wpautop runs but maybe you could run an add_filter beforehand that removes line breaks on short codes.

Comment: @hansvedo if I do remember right, `wpautop()` runs before filters, I think I've tried that one a while ago without success. also @Calle some more insight on this question can be read here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71698/wpautop-when-shortcode-attributes-are-on-new-lines-break-args-array/71723#71723 - I've ended up writing a custom plugin instead, to achieve what I needed, but the question itself is still kind-of unanswered. Thanks both for the suggestions though!

Comment: @Luca I think it hasn't been answered because most people don't want to spend time setting everything up. Look at the shortcode_parse_atts function I mentioned. You probably only need to copy that, and replace \s in the regexp with [\s\n] to include both white space and new line. But then you need to also make your own version of do_shortcode_tag and do_shortcode. Since you already have it set up, you could just try changing the source code temporarily though to see if it works.

Comment: I suggest to close the question here and [keep **the one on wp.se**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71698/wpautop-when-shortcode-attributes-are-on-new-lines-break-args-array). This is really a wordpress question and I'd say this requires fixing within WP core or real WP coding insight better located on the other site.

Comment: I agree this being slightly off topic on SO but sadly it received much more attention on here than on wp.se :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accepted answer - credit to @Stephen

Ok, I've never seen a shortcode done in this way so I threw together a bit of code to test your scenario. And I get the same results with code that works just fine with the standard shortcode format.

**Standard Shortcode Format**

```
[shortcode name1="value1" name2="value2"]
```

I don't believe this is a result of wpautop(), but a result of the way the shortcode attributes are parsed. Look at the example above and you'll see that the only unquoted whitespace is used to separate the shortcode and the name=>value pairs (i.e. no spaces between the name and the '=', only one space between each name=>value pair). In this context the 
 is also considered whitespace.

I've not dug in to the particular internals of shortcode parsing so I can't offer a suggestion on a a hook or filter that would help. Perhaps another user here has some ideas on that.

If you must format your shortcode like you have it I think you're going to have to write custom code to parse the array that's passed to your shortcode function. All the values are there so you should be able to piece them back together.

Another option might be to provide a form for the end-user to enter the values then populate the shortcode in your content.

**An update to my answer**

Something about my answer was bugging me so I looked again. And you are correct wpautop() is having an effect on the output of the page. But I don't think it is the cause of your shortcode problems.